# Visual studio 2017 community Edition - Nuget.exe not found

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package

I have been trying to configure a project level nuget.config file as per the various documentation and instructions I found online from MSDN and other  sources. I have visual studio 2017 community edition installed. I can't seem to find nuget.exe so I can configure the local nuget.config file with my settings as well as tell nuget to use the new project level nuget.config.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#config-section
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior

I launched developer command prompt in administrator mode and when I type NUGET to access nuget.exe, I got error that command not found. 
I am trying to figure out where I need to be so when I run the following command nuget can resolve:

```
nuget config -set repositoryPath=c:\packages -configfile .\myApp\NuGet.Config
```

I get:

> 'nuget' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

I tried searching for nuget.exe everywhere on my machine, but can't seem to find it.

Do I need to re-download and install the exe? It seems that it is already built-in to visual studio and I would ideally like to leverage that same version installed. 
Would appreciate any input, ideas or help.

Many Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer.While the package manager console is available and comes with visual studio 2017. Nuget.exe is not included only the dlls for nuget are. That is clearly outlined in the downloads page of NUGET.

https://www.nuget.org/downloads